# Firebase: If I query a Firestore collection for a record and pass one column of data into a model, would my app do a second query for the next model?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function called `getNotifications` that queries a collection in Firestore. I am running it on my `Notifications` screen.

On this screen, I want to optimize the number of Firestore querying to only query once. When the user gets to this screen, the app should query the data once, determine the `notifID` for the current index, then pass the initial data into the appropriate model. If the `notifID == '1'`, then the initial data should be transformed via the `GroupModel`. If the `notifID == '2'`, then transform via the `FriendRequestModel`. In doing all this, am I correct in assuming that Firestore will only query once, i.e. it will ***not*** re-query when passing the data through either the `GroupModel` or the `FriendRequestModel`? I'm worried because `CommonModel` only needs to read the `notifID`. I'm not even defining any other data fields in it, so I worry that this might signal to the Flutter framework that it needs to re-query.

**notifications.dart**

```
class ScreenNotifications extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenNotifications({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenNotifications> createState() => _ScreenNotificationsState();
}

class _ScreenNotificationsState extends State<ScreenNotifications> {

void initialize() async {
  tempNotifsList = await database.getNotifications();
  setState(() {
    notifsList = tempNotifsList;
  });
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Notifications'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: notifsList?.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                final notif = CommonModel.fromJson(data);
                final notifID = notif.notifID;

                if (notifID == '1') {
                  final group = GroupModel.fromJson(data);
                }

                if (notifID == '2') {
                  final friendRequest = FriendRequestModel.fromJson(data);
                }

              }
              ...//rest of code//
```

**database.dart**

```
Future<List> getNotifications() async {
    final uid = getUID();
    List notifsList = [];
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference notifCollection = firestore.collection('notifications_' + uid);

    final docsRef = await notifCollection.get();
    docsRef.docs.forEach((element) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> docMap = {'docID': element.id, 'data': element.data()};
      notifsList.add(docMap);
    });

    return notifsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to go about this is to the defined a notification type as part of fields while storing your notification,

```
"nofiType":....//here will be group of friends
```

so in your `ListView.builder` then you check if the notif.notiType is equl to the value show the widget

Comment: That's the plan, but what I'm really asking is if the scenario I explained in my question would count as 1 read or 2?